# using copyTo function in google sheets api in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use the copyTo function in google sheets api via node.js wherein it would copy a sheet from one spreadsheet to another. Here is my code:

```
function copySheet(auth){
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
var spreadsheetID_foo = 'some spreadsheet id';
var spreadsheetID_test = 'another spreadsheet id';

sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo({
    auth: auth,
    sheetId: 0,
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetID_test,
    resource: {properties: {destinationSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetID_foo}}
}, function(err,response){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Data :', response);
});
}
```

However, an error pops and says "Missing required parameters: sheetId". But in the code, I already declared the said parameter. I have been successful in using other commands from the API but this copyTo function is one that I cant really figure out. Can someone out here guide me on what I did wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) from Google Apps Script on how to use copyTo(spreadsheet) funtion.

It Copies the sheet to a given spreadsheet, which can be the same spreadsheet as the source. The copied sheet will be named "Copy of [original name]".

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];

 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_GOES HERE');
 sheet.copyTo(destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

// replace

```
resource: {properties: {destinationSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetID_foo}}
```

// with

```
resource: {destinationSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetID_foo}
```